# Matlab: link to variable, not variable value

Tags: matlab, variables

It has been very difficult to use google, MATLAB documentation, I've spent a few hours, and I cannot learn how to

```
x = 1
y = x
x = 10
y

ans = 10
```

what happens instead is:

```
x = 1
y = x
x = 10
y

ans = 1
```

The value of x is stored into y. But I want to dynamically update the value of y to equal x.

What operation do I use to do this?

Thanks.M

Comment: You want to look for pointers in MATLAB. My quick search didn't turn up anything, but that might help you w/ Googling.

Comment: I'm keen to think that you are approaching the problem in the wrong way if you need something that behaves like a pointer... Relevant [comment](http://www.edaboard.com/thread46260.html#post210526), quote: "*why?
why would you need pointers in matlab?
matlab code is a script, which will be compiled to pseudo code in the case of a function. I don't think it's usefull to think about it as you'd do in C++. I guess you should see argument passing as passing by reference.

if you want to reduce the number of arguments, put them in one vector or in a struct.*"

Comment: You don't just need pointer/reference behaviour when passing arguments to functions.  You might want it simply to avoid repetition of x(2).y(4).z(7).w(i) in your code.  And often, you don't want just read-access to the variable/field.  Here, only single-letter variable/field names are used, but in good code, variable/field names are descriptive and hence longer.

Answer (score 18):

Matlab is 99% a pass-by-value environment, which is what you have just demonstrated.  The 1% which is pass-by-reference is handles, either handle graphics (not relevant here) or handle  classes, which are pretty close to what you want.

To use a handle class to do what you describe, put the following into a file call `RefValue`.

```
classdef RefValue < handle
    properties
        data = [];
    end
end
```

This creates a "handle" class, with a single property called "data".

Now you can try:

```
x = RefValue;
x.data = 1;
y = x;
x.data = 10;
disp(y.data)   %Displays 10.
```

Answer (score 8):

you can try something of the following;

```
x=10;
y='x'
y

y = 
    x

eval(y)
x =
    10
```

Comment: Yes, this gets very close.

Answer (score 6):

You can also define an implicit handle on `x` by defining a function on `y` and referring to it:

```
x = 1;
y = @(x) x;
y(x) % displays 1
x = 10;
y(x) % displays 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, this is not possible. However, there are many ways to get similar behavior. For example, you could have an array `a = [1, 5, 3, 1]` and then index it by `x` and `y`. For `x = 2`, you could assign `a(x) = 7`, `y = x`, and once you change `a(x) = 4`, `a(y) == 4`.

So indexing may be the fastest way to emulate references, but if you want some elegant solution, you could go through symbolic variables as @natan points out. What's important to take from this is that there are *no pointers* in MATLAB.