# Reference equality in Matlab struct. Can a struct have multiple field names pointing to the same object?

Tags: matlab, pointers, memory, struct

If I have a `struct` in Matlab with multiple fields defined with the same object, would that be treated as one object in memory or recreated for each field?  In other words, I would like to have multiple field names for one object, is that possible in Matlab?

For example,

```
function output = fn(input)

output = struct('field1',input,'field2',input)

end
```

Would `output` contain two copies of `input` or one?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793453/matlab-link-to-variable-not-variable-value

Comment: Nice. And thanks. Although regarding the examples in that post, a single float variable is typically pass-by-value anyway. Matlab is not being an exception. I still need to know about `struct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found out a way to find an answer. One can type in the followings in the Matlab cmd.

```
A=magic(3);
S=struct('field1',A,'field2',A);
format debug
S.field1
S.field2
```

The output for me was

```
>> S.field1

ans =


Structure address = 369610c0 
m = 3
n = 3
pr = 3fb54e40 
pi = 0
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> S.field2

ans =


Structure address = 369610c0 
m = 3
n = 3
pr = 3fb54e40 
pi = 0
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Note that the `pr` values are the same for both fields.

I think `pr` is the pointer to the real part of the matrix. So since both fields share the same pointer, there is no duplication of the same object.