# How to use a cell array with variable depth as input of a function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, global-variables, cell

I have a global cell array where data is stored in a structure with variable depth. Assume that it has the following structure:

```
global table
table{1,1}.data
table{1,2}.sub{1,1}.data
table{1,2}.sub{1,2}.data
table{1,3}.sub{1,1}.sub{1,1}.data
table{1,3}.sub{1,1}.sub{1,2}.data
```

Now, I want to define a function that can change the data of the `table` variable. The problem is that when I use for instance `table{1,2}.sub{1,2}` as input to my function and let my function change the data, the data in the original `table` variable is not changed.
Sketch:

```
%function
function changedata(region)
    region.data='banana';
end
%main
changedata(table{1,2}.sub{1,2});
```

(I did not yet find information about this problem.)

Comment: `table{1,2}.sub{1,2}` is not a pointer to the element but a copy of it's data (call by value). This is why it does not get changed when writing to it in the function.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793453/matlab-link-to-variable-not-variable-value

Comment: Exactly. If the structure would be of the form `table{1,2,1,2}`, you could use `varargin` in the function and write `table{varargin{:}}`. I had the idea to construct a string (e.g. `table{1,2}.sub{1,2}`), but I do not know whether you can use this to store the new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same argument in the output

```
%function
function region = changedata(region)
    region.data='banana';
end

%main
table{1,2}.sub{1,2} = changedata(table{1,2}.sub{1,2});
```

Otherwise you need a handle class as [Matt mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320408/how-to-use-a-cell-array-with-variable-depth-as-input-of-a-function#comment50628779_31320408).