# MATLAB Variable aliases

Tags: c++, matlab, reference

I am looking for a way to use aliases for MATLAB variables, without incurring performance penalties.

Consider the following scenario: you have a variable with a very long access name, such as a deeply nested struct value, and you'd like to modify this variable locally. The following code will make a copy of the variable as soon as it is modified.

```
S.f1.f2.f3.f4.f5.myvar = ones(very_big_number);
myvar_alias = S.f1.f2.f3.f4.f5.myvar; % both variables still refer to same block of memory
myvar_alias(1) = 0; % copy of large variable made due to modification
```

Is there a way to make this work, like taking a C++ reference?

```
auto myval_alias& = S.f1.f2.f3.f4.f5.myvar
```

I am asking this strictly for avoiding copy-pasting, and for readability of the code. The answers for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793453/matlab-link-to-variable-not-variable-value) try to achieve something that will pass by reference

Comment: The top voted answer in the question you linked is the only true way to pass reference. You'll have to use OOP. Only Matlab objects deriving from the `handle` class allow passing by reference. Every other type is managed by [`lazy-copy/Copy-On-Write`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/).

Comment: @hoky I was hoping there is a simpler answer. I might as well keep on copy-pasting, if this is the situation