# Setting handles from one GUI to another GUI - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab, excuse my amateur coding. I am trying to pass handles from one GUI to another GUI which are two independent GUI's.

for example, I created two GUI's `test1.m` and `test2.m`, in which `test2.m` calls `test1.m` in the opening function. so here I am trying to set the text on the `test1.m` using its handles. But I get an error `Reference to non-existent field test1_text`. I have even tried sending the handles of `test2.m` to `test1.m` by doing `test1(handles)` in the opening function but still I get the same error.

test2.m sets the text in the second GUI:

```
function varargout = test2(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @test2_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @test2_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


function test2_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
test1
guidata(hObject, handles);



function varargout = test2_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


function test2_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
str = sprintf('hello');
set(handles.test1_text,'String',str);
```

test1.m

```
function varargout = test1(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @test1_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @test1_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function test1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);


function varargout = test1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;
```

note that The GUI was developed in Matlab GUIDE.

can anyone advice me on how to do that?

Comment: I find it easier to use handle objects to send data between guis - such as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793453/matlab-link-to-variable-not-variable-value/14793728#14793728

Comment: @bdecaf this is based on class i guess. but i am trying to set the handles when considering functions of GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GUIDE`'s `Inspector` to set `Tag` to your `test1`, i.e `my_test_1`.

In your `test2`, find the object with such `Tag` before use it:

```
function test2_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
obj = findall(0, 'Type', 'figure', 'Tag', 'my_test_1');
my_text = findobj(obj, 'Tag', 'test1_text');
str = sprintf('hello');
set(my_text,'String',str);
```

By the way, you must assure that your `test1` has an object named `test1_text`.

Comment: I get this error `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.`

Comment: have you set your `test1`'s Tag?

Comment: where and how did you set the Tag?

Comment: Right click on the blank space -> property inspector. then I entered the Tag name as my_test_1